# USB 3.0 flash drive won't format - Couldn't open device

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive, formatting

I have a 128GB USB 3.0 flash drive here that won't work anymore. When I insert it, it takes forever to mount, and forever means that it won't mount in the end.

Using the Terminal, I get the following error message:

```
$ diskutil eraseDisk JHFS+ TEST123 /dev/disk4
Started erase on disk4
Unmounting disk
Error: -69877: Couldn't open device
```

And this:

```
$ diskutil verifyVolume /dev/disk4
Error starting file system verification for disk4: Invalid request (-69886)
```

This stick was used on a Yamaha receiver with USB connector, to play MP3s. It still sees the folders, but when I try to open folders with music files in it, it gives an "access error".

All I want is to format the disk. What's on it doesn't matter. How can I get this working?

---

**Update**

Diskutil repair gave the following result:

```
Repairing file system.
Volume is already unmounted.
Performing fsck_msdos -y /dev/rdisk6s1
** /dev/rdisk6s1 (NO WRITE)

could not read boot block (Resource busy)

File system check exit code is 8.
Restoring the original state found as unmounted.
File system verify or repair failed.
Operation failed…
```

And as requested:

```
$ sudo dmesg
Controller][TransportRadioPowerOff] -- returns kIOReturnError because Radio Power State = Powered Off -- inOpCode = 0xFCE9 (Broadcom VSC -- LE Meta VSC), From: Unknown (255), mNumberOfCommandsAllowedByHardware is 1, requestPtr = 0x2000 
Sandbox: 6 duplicate reports for fseventsd deny(1) file-read-metadata /private/var/folders/81/ntbxxvv526gdxxfn_3sdtczm0000gn/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv****[BroadcomBluetoothHostController][TransportRadioPowerOff] -- returns kIOReturnError because Radio Power State = Powered Off -- inOpCode = 0x200E (LE Create Connection Cancel), From: Unknown (255), mNumberOfCommandsAllowedByHardware is 1, requestPtr = 0x2000 

en0: DAD complete for fe80:5::4aa:1364:58c1:444 - no duplicates found.
en0: DAD complete for 2001:982:78ca:1:1ca1:4e07:4b5d:444c - no duplicates found.
en0: DAD complete for 2001:982:78ca:1:b9c8:4f88:af8d:e3a8 - no duplicates found.
AppleCamIn::handleWakeEvent_gated
IOConsoleUsers: time(1) 1534713791->1534713791, lin 1, llk 1, 
IOConsoleUsers: gIOScreenLockState 3, hs 0, bs 0, now 1534755779, sm 0x0

IOConsoleUsers: time(0) 1534713791->0, lin 1, llk 0, 
IOConsoleUsers: gIOScreenLockState 1, hs 0, bs 0, now 0, sm 0x0
AppleKeyStore: operation failed (pid: 92 sel: 75 ret: e00002ce '-536870194', -1, 100000)
utun_ctl_connect: creating interface utun1 (id utunid1)
utun1: attached with 0 suspended link-layer multicast membership(s)
RTC: setGMTTimeOfDay 1534755779
AppleCamIn::handleWakeEvent_gated
Sandbox: 1 duplicate report for fseventsd deny(1) file-read-metadata /private/var/folders/81/ntbxxvv526gdxxfn_3sdtczm0000gn/0/com.apple.nsurlsessiond/5C191B41B85964975463638FAD57F73CB1F3418D/5C191B41B85964975463638FAD57F73CB1F3418Dcom.apple.p2p: updateLocalRequests[10360] : AWDL will be turned ON by \^Ad\^A4\^Ae\^A2\^A1\^Af\^Ae\^Af\^Af\^Af\^A6\^A8\^A8\^Aa\^A0\^Ac\^A0\^A0\^A0\^A0\^A0\^A0\^A0\^A0\^A0\^A0\^A0\^A0\^A0\^A8\^Ae\^Af\^Cip6\^Darpa PTR browse, Called from mDNSResponder (pid 184)
Sandbox: 1 duplicate report for fsavd deny(1) file-read-metadata /private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles/Store/ConfigProfiles.binarycom.apple.p2p: IO80211AWDLPeerManager::setAwdlOperatingMode Setting the AWDL operation mode from AUTO to SUSPENDED
com.apple.p2p: AWDL is suspended
com.apple.p2p: IO80211AWDLPeerManager::setAwdlOperatingMode Setting the AWDL operation mode from SUSPENDED to AUTO
com.apple.p2p: AWDL is off
Sandbox: fseventsd(56) System Policy: deny(1) file-read-metadata /private/var/folders/81/ntbxxvv526gdxxfn_3sdtczm0000gn/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dvFB0: Complete modeset
Starting poll type 4
Restarting poll type 4
Command 0x2 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x5Command 0x1 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x1001Command 0x16 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x40e0Command 0xa completed. inCount: 2 data:0x0Command 0xb completed. inCount: 2 data:0x0Command 0x12 completed. inCount: 2 data:0xffffCommand 0x13 completed. inCount: 2 data:0xffffCommand 0xf completed. inCount: 2 data:0x1760Command 0x10 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x1795SmartBattery: finished polling type 4
FB0: Complete modeset

Command 0x2 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x5Command 0x1 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x1001Command 0x16 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x40e0Command 0x53 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x0Command 0x54 completed. inCount: 2 data:0xe443Command 0xa completed. inCount: 2 data:0x0Command 0xb completed. inCount: 2 data:0x0Command 0xc completed. inCount: 2 data:0x1Command 0x11 completed. inCount: 2 data:0xffffCommand 0x3f completed. inCount: 2 data:0x10daCommand 0x3e completed. inCount: 2 data:0x10daCommand 0x3d completed. inCount: 2 data:0x10d9Command 0x3c completed. inCount: 2 data:0x0Command 0x12 completed. inCount: 2 data:0xffffCommand 0x9 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x328dCommand 0x8 completed. inCount: 2 data:0xbdeCommand 0x17 completed. inCount: 2 data:0xcbCommand 0x13 completed. inCount: 2 data:0xffffCommand 0xf completed. inCount: 2 data:0x1760Command 0x10 completed. inCount: 2 data:0x1795SmartBattery: finished polling type 2

USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): AA515FFJBIUBRWW6J5 0x5dc 0xa83a 0x1100, 3
FB0: Complete modeset
IOConsoleUsers: time(0) 0->0, lin 1, llk 0, 
IOConsoleUsers: gIOScreenLockState 1, hs 0, bs 0, now 0, sm 0x0
loginwindow is not entitled for IOHIDLibUserClient keyboard accessFB0: Complete modeset

IOConsoleUsers: time(0) 0->0, lin 1, llk 0, 
IOConsoleUsers: gIOScreenLockState 1, hs 0, bs 0, now 0, sm 0x0
FB0: Complete modeset
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `dmesg -w` when you connect the USB drive to the OP? (Drive relevant data only is enough)

Comment: @confetti - I've updated the question

Comment: That is after plugging it in? I can't locate anything in there that is related to the USB drive. Usually even broken devices should appear there, simply when the USB controller detects something.

Comment: Yes that's it. See the DiskUtil log as well.